# get diff between two directories in rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get the diff between two directories, e.g.

```
dir1
 - changed.txt
 - deleted.txt
 - index.txt
 - nested
   - changed.txt
   - deleted.txt
   - index.txt

dir2
 - changed.txt
 - added.txt
 - index.txt
 - nested
   - changed.txt
   - added.txt
   - index.txt
}

added:   ["added.txt", "nested/added.txt"]
deleted: ["deleted.txt", "nested/deleted.txt"]
changed: ["changed.txt", "nested/changed.txt"]
```

I was looking at the source code of the [dir-diff](https://github.com/assert-rs/dir-diff) crate and came up with the following solution. As I'm new to rust I'm looking for a better / cleaner way to archive this or some general feedback for my solution.

The code gets a dir walker for both directories and sorts it by the paths of the files. I then loop over both iterators. If the path of `a` is smaller then the path of `b`, I know an element was added. Removed elements are detected in a similar fashion. In this case I only increment one of the iterators. If the paths are equal, the file is in both directories and I simply check the length (In future version I'd like to check the hash as well). If either iterator ends, I have to loop through the remaining entries to get the last added / removed files.

```
use error_chain::error_chain;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::path::Path;
use walkdir::{DirEntry, WalkDir};

error_chain! {
    foreign_links {
        Io(std::io::Error);
        Walkdir(walkdir::Error);
    }
}

fn compare_by_file_path(a: &DirEntry, b: &DirEntry) -> Ordering {
    a.path().cmp(b.path())
}

fn walk_dir<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<walkdir::IntoIter> {
    let mut walkdir = WalkDir::new(path).sort_by(compare_by_file_path).into_iter();
    if let Some(Err(e)) = walkdir.next() {
        Err(e.into())
    } else {
        Ok(walkdir)
    }
}

pub fn get_diff<U: AsRef<Path>, V: AsRef<Path>>(from: U, to: V) -> Result<()> {
    let mut a_walker = walk_dir(from)?;
    let mut b_walker = walk_dir(to)?;

    let mut added: Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new();
    let mut removed: Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new();
    let mut changed: Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new();

    let mut a = a_walker.next().unwrap()?;
    let mut b = b_walker.next().unwrap()?;
    loop {
        match a.file_name().cmp(b.file_name()) {
            Ordering::Less => {
                removed.push(a.path().into());
                a = match a_walker.next() {
                    Some(entry) => entry?,
                    None => break,
                };
            }
            Ordering::Greater => {
                added.push(b.path().into());
                b = match b_walker.next() {
                    Some(entry) => entry?,
                    None => break,
                };
            }
            Ordering::Equal => {
                if a.metadata()?.len() != b.metadata()?.len() {
                    changed.push(b.path().into());
                }

                a = match a_walker.next() {
                    Some(entry) => entry?,
                    None => break,
                };
                b = match b_walker.next() {
                    Some(entry) => entry?,
                    None => break,
                };
            }
        }
    }

    for a in a_walker {
        removed.push(a?.path().into());
    }

    for b in b_walker {
        added.push(b?.path().into());
    }

    let output = (added, removed, changed);
    Ok(output)
}
}
```

Output:

```
(
   ["./tests/test2/nested/new.ts", "./tests/test2/new.ts"],
   ["./tests/test1/deleted.ts", "./tests/test1/nested/deleted.ts"],
   ["./tests/test2/changed.ts", "./tests/test2/nested/changed.ts"]
)
```

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind: For larger filesystems, an iterator based approach would probably be benefitial, to avoid large vector copies.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if let Some(Err(e)) = walkdir.next()` in `walk_dir`?

Comment: @Finomnis, it is because of this: https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/struct.IntoIter.html#method.next . The errors are returned wrapped in Some.

Comment: @Finomnis I would agree, but I have no clue how to implement it with iterators efficiently. The iterator would not guarantee that the files in both directories are visited in the same order afaik. So I would have to go through the iterators multiple times to detect if a file is missing or was added / changed. This would increase the complexity but reduce the memory footprint I guess. I actually tried it this way first but had problems with the lifetimes of the nested iterators.

Comment: Seems the first `walkdir.next()` removes the `.` entry, the self-referencial directory.

Comment: Missing import `PathBuf` and incorrect return type of `get_diff`.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the problem a bit, just for fun.

Here's a completely different approach:

```
use error_chain::error_chain;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use walkdir::{DirEntry, WalkDir};

error_chain! {
    foreign_links {
        Io(std::io::Error);
        Walkdir(walkdir::Error);
    }
}

fn compare_by_file_path(a: &DirEntry, b: &DirEntry) -> Ordering {
    a.path().cmp(b.path())
}

fn walk_dir<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<walkdir::IntoIter> {
    let mut walkdir = WalkDir::new(path).sort_by(compare_by_file_path).into_iter();
    if let Some(Err(e)) = walkdir.next() {
        Err(e.into())
    } else {
        Ok(walkdir)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Difference {
    Added(PathBuf),
    Removed(PathBuf),
    Changed(PathBuf),
}

pub fn get_diff<U: AsRef<Path>, V: AsRef<Path>>(
    from: U,
    to: V,
) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = Result<Difference>>> {
    let mut a_walker = walk_dir(from)?;
    let mut b_walker = walk_dir(to)?;

    let mut a = None;
    let mut b = None;

    let mut get_next_change = move || {
        Ok(loop {
            if a.is_none() {
                a = a_walker.next().transpose()?;
            }
            if b.is_none() {
                b = b_walker.next().transpose()?;
            }

            if a.is_none() {
                break b.take().map(|b| Difference::Added(b.path().into()));
            } else if b.is_none() {
                break a.take().map(|a| Difference::Removed(a.path().into()));
            } else {
                match a
                    .as_ref()
                    .unwrap()
                    .file_name()
                    .cmp(b.as_ref().unwrap().file_name())
                {
                    Ordering::Less => {
                        break a.take().map(|a| Difference::Removed(a.path().into()));
                    }
                    Ordering::Greater => {
                        break b.take().map(|b| Difference::Added(b.path().into()));
                    }
                    Ordering::Equal => {
                        let a = a.take().unwrap();
                        let b = b.take().unwrap();

                        if a.metadata()?.len() != b.metadata()?.len() {
                            break Some(Difference::Changed(b.path().into()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        })
    };

    Ok(std::iter::from_fn(move || get_next_change().transpose()))
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "{:#?}",
        get_diff("dir1", "dir2")
            .unwrap()
            .collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>()
            .unwrap()
    );
}
```

```
[
    Added(
        "dir2/added.txt",
    ),
    Changed(
        "dir2/changed.txt",
    ),
    Removed(
        "dir1/deleted.txt",
    ),
    Added(
        "dir2/nested/added.txt",
    ),
    Changed(
        "dir2/nested/changed.txt",
    ),
    Removed(
        "dir1/nested/deleted.txt",
    ),
]
```

Although I think there isn't really any point to using iterators as long as we are using `WalkDir::new(path).sort_by`. It would only make sense if we used folder-wise iterators. But `WalkDir.sort_by` loads all files first, then sorts them, and then iterates over them. Meaning: the entire files list is loaded to memory already, and using an iterator gives no further benefit.